# sscanf_s: format string '%d' requires an argument of type 'int *', but variadic argument 4 has type 'WORD *'

Tags: c++, c, warnings

```
SYSTEMTIME ConvertStringToSystemTime(const char *dateTimeString) const 
{

    SYSTEMTIME systime;
    memset(&systime, 0, sizeof(systime));
    // Date string should be "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss:mss"
    auto u = sscanf_s(dateTimeString, "%d/%d/%d%d:%d:%d:%d:%d",
        &systime.wDay,
        &systime.wMonth,
        &systime.wYear,
        &systime.wHour,
        &systime.wMinute,
        &systime.wSecond,
        &systime.wMilliseconds);
    return systime;
}
```

My whole problem being is that I'm reading a date from a file, which is stored in a string variable, and I need to subtract the current Systemtime to the one read from the file.

And I was trying to sort it out by converting the string to Systemtime, and then get the difference, but after trying out this function, I keep getting that warning error which I must fix but don't know how exactly.

Comment: Yeah, there's an extra one at the end, thank you for pointing that out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use %hu instead of %d.

Explanation: The fields of [SYSTEMTIME](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/minwinbase/ns-minwinbase-systemtime) fields are of type [WORD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winprog/windows-data-types#WORD), which is defined as

```
typedef unsigned short WORD;
```

Reading type `unsigned short` requires `%hu` as described [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf).

Answer (score 0):

In windows, WORD is defined as `unsigned short`, so it needs `%u` instead of `%d`.

Comment: %u reads an `unsigned int`, not short. https://stackoverflow.com/a/35296206/4955498